# http/https Rewrite not working, adds index.php to path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add some secure pages to a site. The links in the site all use the current protocol (i.e. are protocol independent, paths start with `//`).

I need the paths `/info/season-tickets/*` and `/ticketcontroller/*` to use https, and all others using http.

I've tried building rules to do the following (ignoring the ticketcontroller part for now):

```
If Port==80 and Path==/info/season-tickets/, rewrite with https
If Port==443 and Path!=/info/season-tickets/, rewrite with http
```

However, when I access `/info/season-tickets/`, rather than redirecting to the https version, I get `example.com/index.php/info/season-tickets`

The .htaccess is below - my attempts are below `# Force https on certain pages` and `# Force http everywhere else`, and the other bits are from the Kohana framework

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Force https on certain pages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/info/season-tickets/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Force http everywhere else
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/info/season-tickets/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I tried re-ordering the rules to see if that fixed it, but it didn't.

Any ideas why this isn't working (`http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/` shows that it should work)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue, not with htaccess, but in the index.php file (all requests go through this).

By default, I assume port `80`. Then, if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is in an array of secure paths, I switch the variable to `443`.

Then, if `$required_port != $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`, I redirect and `exit()`.